# Is there any way to execute a stored procedure within a cursor?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

"query" is string variable and I am appending result by executing following.

```
FOR x IN
    (SELECT Years FROM School_Years)
LOOP
    query := query || x.Year || ',' ;            
END LOOP;
```

My question: I already have stored procedure (GetSchoolYears) "SELECT Years FROM School_Years".

Instead of "SELECT Years FROM School_Years", how can I use stored procedure name? Something like......

```
FOR x IN
    (GetSchoolYears)
LOOP
    query := query || x.Year || ',' ;            
END LOOP;
```

or any other idea to use result of that stored procedure within IN (---)

--------Stored procedure------------

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE GetSchoolYears
(

   p_cursor IN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR 

) AS 
BEGIN

 OPEN p_cursor FOR 

SELECT Years FROM School_Years;

END GetSchoolYears;
```

Comment: Pls, post the stored procedure (at least the signature). Does it return a cursor as an OUT parameter?

Comment: No, you cannot call procedures from SQL. The nearest thing would be to define a table function; or else have the procedure return a ref cursor and step through that. However you can't use a Cursor FOR loop with a ref cursor.

Comment: it is unclear what the pl/sql function/procedure getschoolyears returns. If it returns a string it can be directly assigned to a pl/sql variable.

Comment: Hi, I modified my question by adding stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is what you expect but this is how to use a ref cursor in PL/SQL.

```
declare 
    rc sys_refcursor;
    l_rec School_Years.years%type;
    query varchar2(2000);
begin
    GetSchoolYears(rc);
    loop
        fetch rc into l_rec;
        exit when rc%notfound;
        query := query || l_rec || ',' ;     
    end loop;
    dbms_output.put_line(query);
end;
/
```